# send email using php

Tags: php, email

How do I know if my host is allowing me to send emails using PHP mail() function?

Is that possible to check with phpinfo() output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check the `phpinfo()` but I would suggest trying

```
mail("me@me.com", 'Subject', 'Test Body', "From: from@me.com");
```

Comment: Doesn't the last parameter need a `from: ` prefix?

Answer (score 6):

> IS that possible to check with phpinfo() output?

Not always, and not reliably. But why not simply try out?

```
mail("youraddress@domain.com", "Test subject", "Test body");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fsock open on the mail server's port also. This is playing on nightmare mode however.